# Creating Spark Objects from JPEG and using spark_apply() on a non-translated function

Tags: r, binary, jpeg, sparklyr

Typically when one wants to use `sparklyr` on a custom function (*i.e.* [**non-translated functions) they place them within `spark_apply()`](https://sparkfromr.com/non-translated-functions-with-spark-apply.html). However, I've only encountered examples where a *single* local data frame is either `copy_to()` or `spark_read_csv()` to a remote data source and then used `spark_apply()` on it. An example, for illustrative purposes only:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

n_sim = 100
iris_samps <- iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == "virginica") %>%
  sapply(rep.int, times=n_sim) %>% cbind(replicate = rep(1:n_sim, each = 50)) %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
  dplyr::group_by(replicate) %>%
  dplyr::sample_n(50, replace = TRUE)

iris_samps_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris_samps)

iris_samps_tbl %>% 
  spark_apply(function(x) {mean(x$Petal_Length)}, 
    group_by = "replicate") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = result)) + geom_histogram(bins = 20) + ggtitle("Histogram of 100 Bootstrapped Means using sparklyr")
```

It seems like it would be therefore possible to use this on any range of non-translated functions coming from `CRAN` or `Bioconductor` packages as long as the data resides in a Spark Object.

I've came up with a specific problem for `.jpeg` images as I read that [`SparkR` can load compressed image (`.jpeg`, `.png`, *etc.*) into raw image representation via `ImageIO` in Java library](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-datasource) - it seems possible that `sparklyr` could do this as well.

`RsimMosaic::composeMosaicFromImageRandom(inputImage, outputImage, pathToTilesLibrary)` function takes an input image and a path to tiles used to create a photo mosaic and outputs an image ([example here](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2020/02/13/photo-mosaics-in-r/)).

If this function only took one image and I knew how to turn it into spark object I might imagine the command would look like: `composeMosaicFromImageRandom(inputImage, outputImage, spark_obj)`. However, this function is taking a path to 30,000 images.

How would one create 30,000 Spark Objects from the path to these tiles (`.jpegs`)  and then use this function?

If the underlying code would actually need to be modified I've used `jimhester/lookup` to provide the source code:

```
function (originalImageFileName, outputImageFileName, imagesToUseInMosaic, 
        useGradients = FALSE, removeTiles = TRUE, fracLibSizeThreshold = 0.7, 
        repFracSize = 0.25, verbose = TRUE) 
{
        if (verbose) {
                cat(paste("\n ------------------------------------------------ \n"))
                cat(paste("    R Simple Mosaic composer - random version   \n"))
                cat(paste(" ------------------------------------------------ \n\n"))
        }
        if (verbose) {
                cat(paste("    Creating the library... \n"))
        }
        libForMosaicFull <- createLibraryIndexDataFrame(imagesToUseInMosaic, 
                saveLibraryIndex = F, useGradients = useGradients)
        libForMosaic <- libForMosaicFull
        filenameArray <- list.files(imagesToUseInMosaic, full.names = TRUE)
        originalImage <- jpeg::readJPEG(filenameArray[1])
        xTileSize <- dim(originalImage[, , 1])[1]
        yTileSize <- dim(originalImage[, , 1])[2]
        if (verbose) {
                cat(paste("    -- Tiles in the Library : ", length(libForMosaic[, 
                        1]), "\n"))
                cat(paste("    -- Tile dimensions : ", xTileSize, " x ", 
                        yTileSize, "\n"))
        }
        if (verbose) {
                cat(paste("\n"))
                cat(paste("    Reading the original image... \n"))
        }
        originalImage <- jpeg::readJPEG(originalImageFileName)
        xOrigImgSize <- dim(originalImage[, , 1])[1]
        yOrigImgSize <- dim(originalImage[, , 1])[2]
        if (verbose) {
                cat(paste("    -- Original image dimensions : ", xOrigImgSize, 
                        " x ", yOrigImgSize, "\n"))
                cat(paste("    -- Output image dimensions : ", ((xOrigImgSize - 
                        2) * xTileSize), " x ", ((yOrigImgSize - 2) * yTileSize), 
                        "\n"))
        }
        if (verbose) {
                cat(paste("\n"))
                cat(paste("    Computing the mosaic... \n"))
        }
        outputImage <- array(dim = c(((xOrigImgSize - 2) * xTileSize), 
                ((yOrigImgSize - 2) * yTileSize), 3))
        removedList <- c()
        l <- 1
        pCoord <- matrix(nrow = ((xOrigImgSize - 2) * (yOrigImgSize - 
                2)), ncol = 2)
        for (i in 2:(xOrigImgSize - 1)) {
                for (j in 2:(yOrigImgSize - 1)) {
                        pCoord[l, 1] <- i
                        pCoord[l, 2] <- j
                        l <- l + 1
                }
        }
        npixels <- length(pCoord[, 1])
        for (i in 1:npixels) {
                idx <- round(runif(1, 1, length(pCoord[, 1])))
                pixelRGBandNeigArray <- computeStatisticalQuantitiesPixel(pCoord[idx, 
                        1], pCoord[idx, 2], originalImage, useGradients)
                tileFilename <- getCloseMatch(pixelRGBandNeigArray, 
                        libForMosaic)
                startI <- (pCoord[idx, 1] - 2) * xTileSize + 1
                startJ <- (pCoord[idx, 2] - 2) * yTileSize + 1
                outputImage[startI:(startI + xTileSize - 1), startJ:(startJ + 
                        yTileSize - 1), ] <- jpeg::readJPEG(tileFilename)
                if (removeTiles) {
                        libForMosaic <- removeTile(tileFilename, libForMosaic)
                        removedList <- c(removedList, tileFilename)
                        if (length(libForMosaic[, 1]) < (fracLibSizeThreshold * 
                                length(libForMosaicFull[, 1]))) {
                                idxs <- runif(round(0.25 * length(libForMosaicFull[, 
                                        1])), 1, length(removedList))
                                for (ii in 1:length(idxs)) {
                                        libForMosaic <- addBackTile(removedList[idxs[ii]], 
                                                libForMosaic, libForMosaicFull)
                                }
                                removedList <- removedList[-idxs]
                        }
                }
                if (length(pCoord[, 1]) > 2) {
                        pCoord <- pCoord[-idx, ]
                }
        }
        if (verbose) {
                cat(paste("\n"))
                cat(paste("    Done!\n\n"))
        }
        jpeg::writeJPEG(outputImage, outputImageFileName)
}
```

*Please Note:* My first attempt to speed up this code was 1) using `profvis` to find the bottlenecks (*i.e.* the for-loops) 2) use the `foreach` package on for-loops. This resulted in slower code which suggested I was parallelising at too low of a level. As I understand `sparklyr` is more about distributing the computing than about parallelizing it so perhaps this could work.

Comment: A long post; what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to use `sparklyr` on non-translated functions, specifically for `composeMosaicFromImageRandom()`.

Comment: Have you successfully used `spark_apply()` on a single `.jpeg`? The help says that  you need to provide >An object (usually a spark_tbl) coercable to a Spark DataFrame.